# Referencing the element that's calling a controller function Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-model

Fairly simple but I can't figure out the term I need to google.
How do I reference whichever element is calling the controllers blurr function?

## html

```
<body ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="Cntrlr as cntrlr">
    <input type="text" ng-model="cntrlr.inpt" ng-blur="cntrlr.blurr()" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="cntrlr.second" ng-blur="cntrlr.blurr()" />
  </div>
</body>
```

## js

```
var app = angular.module("test", []);
app.controller("Cntrlr", ["$scope", function($scope){
  this.blurr = function(){
    alert("which input am I?");
    alert("this is so meta.");
    // ?
  };
}]);
```

#### [edit]

I realized I meant to be more abstract than I was so I created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616524/referencing-the-element-that-is-calling-a-controller-function-angularjs-ng-cha) because this one has been solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the `$event` to the function, and figure out the target of the event from that:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="cntrlr.inpt" ng-blur="cntrlr.blurr($event)" />
<input type="text" ng-model="cntrlr.second" ng-blur="cntrlr.blurr($event)" />
```

And

```
$scope.blurr = function(event){
    var $this = $(event.target);
    console.log($this);
};
```